# What is MEHT (minimum eye height over the threshold)?

Tags: approach, ils, papi, vasi

What is MEHT (minimum eye height over the threshold)? I can't find the definition and how to use it.

[image]

Comment: I saw this post, but I couldn't understand how I should understand and interpret it. For the sake of clarity, I leave a picture of the part where I saw this expression.

Comment: I guess if I go below 18 feet above the threshold I won't be able to see the VASI lights. Is it simply that way?

Comment: It's not quite that simple.   This video may provide some useful information.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YzIWTtxkfOk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MEHT (Minimum Eye Height over Threshold) is composed of two values: the EWH (the eye to wheel height) plus the WTH (wheel to threshold height). Both values are for the aircraft in the approach configuration and are not the dimensions as may be measured for a parked aircraft resting on the ground. The MEHT assumes that the pilot eye would follow the lower limit of the approach corridor which is defined by angle M = B minus 2 minutes of arc. You can see this in the image below:

[image]

Source:

- [Precision Approach Path Indicator Harmonization with Instrument Landing System](https://tc.canada.ca/en/aviation/reference-centre/advisory-circulars/advisory-circular-ac-no-302-009)